# Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: django, linux, postgresql

Tengo una aplicacion de DJANGO en un servidor (digitalocean). Siguiendo un tutorial he puesto la aplicacion en produccion con gunicorn, nginx, supervisor y postgres. Ha funcionado correctamente, pero despues reinicie el servidor (reboot) y ya no me conecta a la base de datos, ni desde la consola en localhost, ni desde /admin en el navegador ni desde pgAdmin.

El servicio postgrest esta corriendo:

```
sudo service postgresql status
```

> 

```
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS    Loaded: loaded
> (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset:
> enabled)    Active: active (exited) since jue 2017-10-19 22:08:00 UTC;
> 9min ago   Process: 2167 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited,
> status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 2167 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
> 
> oct 19 22:08:00 ubuntu-512mb-nyc1-01 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL
> RDBMS... oct 19 22:08:00 ubuntu-512mb-nyc1-01 systemd[1]: Started
> PostgreSQL RDBMS.

netstat -na
```

> 

```
active Internet connections (servers and established)
>     Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
>     tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
>     tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
>     tcp        0    316 67.207.91.208:22        95.20.34.170:39956      ESTABLISHED
>     tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN



nmap -p 5432 -PN Localhost

> Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-10-19 22:20 UTC Nmap
> scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1) Host is up (0.00017s latency).
> PORT     STATE  SERVICE 5432/tcp closed postgresql
```

Por lo tanto el problema es que el puerto esta cerrado, no??

El archivo  postgresql.conf tiene este aspecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo pg_hba.conf tiene este aspecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando UBUNTU.

como puedo abrir el puerto??

Que solucion me dais??

Comment: Revisa la configuración de postgres, específicamente el archivo `pg_hba.conf ` o equivalente (te diría donde está, pero no especificas tu sistema operativo). Si es cierto que el servicio se está ejecutando deberías ser capaz de entrar desde la consola. Intenta eso, si no puedes con tu usuario, inténtalo de nuevo desde el usuario `postgres`. Actualiza tu pregunta con la información faltante.

Comment: Estoy utilizando Ubuntu. He actualizado mi pregunta con el aspecto de pg_hba.con y de postgresql.conf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despues de varios dias por fin he dado con la solucion al problema.

Por lo visto al instalar postgres hay que decirle que version quieres instalar.

Por lo tanto lo que hice fue desinstalar postgres e instalarlo de nuevo pero poniendo manualmente la ultima version.

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql-9.6


$ sudo apt install postgresql-9.6
```